# Heroku is running two workers in one dyno

Tags: python, heroku

I just started working with Heroku, and I am writing a web server that should place clients in queues when they send an HTTP POST request. This doesn't work for some reason, and I'm guessing it's because there are two workers in one dyno. The console output when I restart is shown below.

```
2018-07-17T06:27:01.144106+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-07-17 06:27:01 +0000] [8] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 8
2018-07-17T06:27:01.195185+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-07-17 06:27:01 +0000] [9] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 9
2018-07-17T06:27:01.736853+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-07-17 06:27:01,736] WARNING in server: Running server.py Time:1736420
2018-07-17T06:27:01.738896+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-07-17 06:27:01,738] WARNING in server: Running server.py Time:1738442
```

I'm not exactly sure what causes it, can someone help? Parts of the Python code are below. It doesn't throw errors, just runs twice. I don't want two servers because it's supposed to be for a game. Having two different lists of games doesn't really work out. Also, if a player gets added to one of the queues and attempts to find out if it has joined a game yet, 50% of the time it accesses the wrong queue because there are two of them and it ends up throwing an error. Is there another solution other than removing one of the workers?

*server.py*

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = 'DEBUG' in os.environ
sockets = Sockets(app)
app.logger.warning('Running server.py Time: {}'.format(datetime.now().time().microsecond + datetime.now().time().second * 1000000))
games = [Game([], -1, 0)]
PLAYER_COUNT = 8
```

*PROCFILE*

```
web: gunicorn server:app
```

If there's any other info that I need to provide, please let me know. This is both my first time working with Heroku, Flask, gunicorn, and Python.

I usually work in Java so this is really challenging for me; if there is anything I'm doing wrong, just let me know(preferably nicely). The PROCFILE is probably wrong, but I'm not sure what any of it does so I'll leave it as it is for now.

Comment: I did not see that.  If you want to put that as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[It's in the docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-gunicorn#basic-configuration) *The WEB_CONCURRENCY environment variable is automatically set by Heroku, based on the processes’ Dyno size*.